# Root access issue from localhost

Tags: centos6, localhost, root

I have a strange root access issue - I'm able to login as root via SSH but I'm not able login to the physical machine via terminal.

Some more info:

```
- running CentOS 6.4
- password authentication (no SSH key)
- nothing found for root at /var/log/secure
- I'm using terminal (KVM) connected directly to the localhost machine
```

/etc/securetty is

```
console
vc/1
vc/2
vc/3
vc/4
vc/5
vc/6
vc/7
vc/8
vc/9
vc/10
vc/11
tty1
tty2
tty2
tty3
tty4
tty5
tty6
tty7
tty8
tty9
tty10
tty11
```

Any clue what can be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you SSHing in with a key or a password? What do the authentication logs say? What error do you get when attempting to log in? Are you sure you're connecting to the same machines (i.e. DNS/IP haven't changed unexpectedly)? Throw us a bone here, dude.

Comment: Added more info

Comment: Set the root password (again) to be sure. And check the contents of `/etc/securetty`.

Comment: Why does then SSH root access/pass works and locally not?

Comment: +1 for "what do the authentication logs say".

Answer (score 2):

I guess you missing KVM port in /etc/sercuretty.

Do this:

```
echo "ttyS*" >> /etc/securetty
```

where `*` is the port number that KVM connect to.

Then try to login.

Comment: I'm using Tripp Lite KVM B020-U08-19 (USB/PS version). Will check it ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance that you got a dysfonctionnal keyboard ? It could be a physical problem or simply a charset/keymap problem.

Maybe you try to use a very simple password (just for the test case) and try to type your password in place of the login, at the prompt, to see if it echoes the password you are willing to enter.

Cheers.

K.

Comment: Used with test user on same machine, password slightly different from root - works, so I think keyboard (or mapping) is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything in /etc/security/access.conf (or in another file) that should prevent Root from gaining a local access ?
Can you, from your test user, make an "su -" ?

Comment: /etc/security/access.conf - all related to root is commented out. Yes, I'm able to do "su -".